# Transparent NSWindow, but not subviews?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

Is it possible to have a transparent NSWindow, but not for it's subviews (NSTextField and NSButton). Right now the text is also showing wat's below, I'd like that to be 0% transparent.

Here's what I do in the NSWindow init:

```
[self setAlphaValue:0.9];
[self setOpaque:NO];
[self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: so you want the nswindow to be transparent in bits and chunks? somepart transparent some not!!!

Comment: Yes, I want the text to be clearly readable, non-transparent in a transparent nswindow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a dark backgound image having the default colour of window behind each of textfield and button.

For this purpose you can subclass all required objects and add the above.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. Since the window is transparent (0.90) you can't have a background image that is the same as the color of the window. The color changes depending on where the window is located.

Comment: Can't you draw a nsview on top that that window?